# Number of vectors spanning a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a rule that number of vectors spanning $\mathbb{R}^n$  must be at least $n$?

For example, can three vectors span $\mathbb{R}^4$ ?

Comment: Yes. Three vectors cannot span $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: Actually, I remembered this from my linear algebra course; however, I could not make sure it because I cannot find a proof. If you know a website which contains it's proof, could you give me it's link ?

Comment: The dimension of a finite dimensional vector space is the number of independent vectors in any spanning set. All spanning sets for a vector space will have the same such number.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ spans it, then $\#S\geqslant n$.